# macOS terminal bug "can't see typed characters" after execution ffmpeg coommand inside shell script

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, ffmpeg, terminal

**I execute from Terminal:**

```
sh 1.sh
```

**1.sh contents:**

```
#!/bin/bash
S1=$(ffmpeg -i correct.wav -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.1 -f null -  2>&1 | grep silence_duration -m 1 | awk '{print $NF}')
echo $S1
```

**After execution I can't see any typed characters in macOS Terminal.** Only invisible typing `reset` helps to solve the problem, but all previous output clears.

How can I modify the code to solve this bug? I guess the problem somewhere in `2>&1`.

**Bug screenshot if press enter several times after script execution:**
[image: bug if press enter several times after script execution]

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remove it, string "S1" value is lost. Is there any other ways?

Comment: It outputs "At least one output file must be specified"

Comment: The main goal to grep silence_duration value into string, output file not needed. But if there is any ffmpeg hack, output fill format could be any ".wav", ".mp3",".webm".

Comment: If `ffmpeg -i correct.wav -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.1 -f null -  2>&1` can't run properly, you need to fix it first before piping it to `grep`. Are you sure the `correct.wav` is in the same path as the shell script?

Comment: If I run directly in Terminal: "ffmpeg -i correct.wav -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.1 -f null - 2>&1" it runs correctly. But if it inside 1.sh file it has this strange bug.

Comment: I've attached to the question bug screenshot what happens if I press key "Enter" several times. It seems it breaks Terminal new lines.

Comment: Can't duplicate this issue on macOS 10.13.2.

Comment: My macOS version 10.11.6. FFMPEG installed via Homebrew, ffmpeg version 3.4.

Comment: macOS 10.13.2, also cannot duplicate error.  I'm using an older ffmpeg version 2.4.3.

Comment: for debugging purposes I found to add to code end "sleep 60" and make script interruption with "ctrl+c", it helps not to type "reset" every time. not best solution, but better than nothing.

Comment: `ffmpeg` is the only part of the command that might alter your stty settings.  If so, it's changing the *input* stream.  If it can run redirected, say, from `/dev/null`:  "ffmpeg </dev/null" -- then making that change would deter it from changing the settings.